# SVG image not display on Safari browser

Tags: javascript, svg, safari, svg-animate

I have one problem which I don't know how to resolve it.

I have one SVG image and I have added animation on it using CSS it works fine in Chrome and Mozilla except in Safari.

The problem is that I can't see the image displayed in Safari.

```
 <object
   type="image/svg+xml"
   class="img-sth"
   height="150"
   width="150"
   data="/img/image.svg">
 </object>
```

I have added animation on it using CSS:

```
.img-sth {
  position: absolute;
  height: 80px;
  top: -3px;
  left: 16px;
  -webkit-animation:spin-faster 4s linear 0.01s infinite;
  -moz-animation:spin-faster 4s linear 0.01s infinite;
  animation:spin-faster 4s linear 0.01s infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes spin-faster { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin-faster { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes spin-faster { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } }
```

Any idea?

Comment: Does it work when you directly place the SVG code in your page instead of using an object?

Comment: @somethinghere I didn't try that way, can you give me instructions how should I change that? I have <img> tag before but again on the some like in the object tag.

Comment: Just open the SVG file and copy it contents, then replace the `object` tag with the actual SVG contents (SVG is just a sort-of HTML file anyway so you can place it straight into your page)